# What is a subinterval?

Tags: statistics, terminology

I got a specific question, and I think I'm forgetting some of my terminology, specifically what a subinterval is. Here is the question

3 engineers work on a cluster which has a daily limit of 2 compute ’credits’. When the total daily amount of compute credits of the three engineers exceeds that daily limit, the company is charged a one thousand dollar penalty. Assume each engineer’s daily cluster usage in compute credits is distributed between 0 and 1 and that the chance the usage belongs in some subinterval of [0, 1] is equal to the length of the subinterval. Assume also that the daily usages of the engineers across the year are independent. Estimate the total cost over 100 days.

I changed the question around some because I want to solve it myself but needed to provide context.

There is one sentence here that I don't quite understand

```
Assume each engineer’s daily cluster usage in compute credits is distributed between 0 and 1 
and that the chance the usage belongs in some subinterval of [0, 1] is equal to the length of the subinterval
```

What is this sentence telling me? For the 1st part, do I assume normal distribution?
What does it the 2nd part mean, about the chance of the usage belonging in the subinterval? If the length is 1, then wouldn't the chance be 100%?

The sense I get is that each engineer uses somewhere between 0-1 usage every day and that usage is normally distributed, so on average they would use 1.5 credits a day. Is my thinking correct here?

Comment: It can't be normally distributed if it's bounded between 0 and 1.

Comment: Can you put up the answer if you were able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$J$ is a subinterval of $I$ if $J$ and $I$ are intervals and $J\subset I$.

So, taking the subinterval $[a,b]$ of $[0,1]$ (for $0\le a\le b\le 1$) that  sentence says that if $0\le a\le b\le 1$ then $P(a\le X\le b)=b-a$; in other words, $X$ is *uniformly* distributed on $[0,1]$.

Comment: So what the sentence is telling me is that each engineer's daily cluster usage is uniformly distributed on [0,1]. Would that indicate that the probability an engineer of using less than .5 credits = using more than .5 credits in that they would both be .5?